# How to get information about logged in user by google plus api?

Tags: google-plus

I am using the Google Plus API to get information about the logged in user. I wrote the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/114518101688116406504?key=AIzaSyCedmALgpuHY1FjfwKBg6LOeo-OxCxgPKc
```

But with this link, I am only able to access the user with `id="114518101688116406504"`. I want information for the current logged in user. 
 For example, in Facebook's API we write `/me`.

What parameter should I include in my URL so that I can access the current logged in user's information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special id of *me* instead of the userid for this as well. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get for further details.